# PHP pdo_dblib extension works via HTTP but not via CLI

Tags: php, command-line-interface, cpanel, sybase

One of our customers uses the pdo_dblib PHP extension to connect to an external Sybase database using FreeTDS.

The connection works perfectly through HTTP requests, but when he calls the PHP script through CLI (using PHP binary), the connection fails:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (connection_name) (severity 9)
```

The strange thing is that running through root user works, but not through their user.

Worth mentioning that this is hosted on a cPanel server, so maybe it has something to do with it.

Comment: My first guess is permissions on the library. Maybe compare pdo_dblib to another active extension?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I have checked the .so extension file, the permission looked a little bit different from the others, but even changing it, it still doesn't work. The extension is owned by root:root. I tried setting freetds.conf to 777 too, but it didn't help. I don't think it is a problem with the extension (at least with the .so), because it recognizes the extension, it just can't find the connection (which is defined in freetds.conf) or connect to it.